# I keep getting the "Invalid hook call." error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a navbar using react.js but i got this error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

This is my code in index.js

```
import { Nav, NavLink, NavMenu } from './NavbarElements'

const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Nav>
                <NavLink to='/'>
                    <h1>Logo</h1>
                </NavLink>
                <NavMenu>
                    <NavLink to='/home' activeStyle>
                        Home
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink to='/about' activeStyle>
                        About
                    </NavLink>
                </NavMenu>
            </Nav>
        </>
    );
};

export default Navbar;
```

and this is my code in NavbarElements.js

```
import { NavLink as Link } from 'react-router-dom';




export const Nav = styled.nav`
    background: #000;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0.5rem calc((100wv - 1000px) /2);
    z-index: 10;
`;
export const NavLink = styled(Link)`
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 lrem;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;

    &.active{
        color: #15cdfc;
    }
`;
export const NavMenu = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 24px;

    @media screen and (max-width:768px) {
        display: none;
    }
`;
```

I am a really new programmer so I apologise in advance if I am making a stupid mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Is `styled` a hook? or in what line of your code are you getting the error?

Comment: I see no issue in the code you've shared. Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/i-keep-getting-the-invalid-hook-call-error-omilb) with it. I suspect you may be using incompatible versions of React or some other package. Can you share your `package.json` file so we can track what versions of `react`, `react-dom`, `react-router-dom`, and `styled-components` you are using?

Comment: I have added my package.json down below

Comment: You should really update your question to include the new relevant details, not add it as an answer. From what I can tell your root `package.json` uses the same versions (all latest) as used in my linked sandbox. I'm curios though what you mean by "And the one in my src" where it seems you've a second `package.json` file. There shouldn't be an additional one in the project's `src` directory. Can you clarify this for us?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add import React from “react”, at the first line, as you are not importing react you cant make use of hooks